# where, oh where, has xml2 gone?

Tags: source, xml2

I've recommended the `xml2` package several times.  It's a useful tool to convert reasonably well-formed XML data into a line-oriented format that can be searched with `grep` or `awk` etc for simple extractions.  Even simple changes using the corresponding `2xml` program in the package.

The debian package description says:

```
Package: xml2
Source: xml2 (0.4-3.1)
Version: 0.4-3.1+b1
Installed-Size: 66
Maintainer: Patrick Schoenfeld <schoenfeld@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libxml2 (>= 2.7.4)
Description-en: Convert between XML, HTML, CSV and a line-oriented format
 xml2 tools are used to convert XML, HTML and CSV to and from a
 line-oriented format more amenable to processing by classic Unix
 pipeline processing tools, like grep, sed, awk, cut, shell scripts,
 and so forth.
Homepage: http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/
Tag: interface::commandline, role::program, use::converting,
 works-with-format::html, works-with-format::xml, works-with::text
Section: utils
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/x/xml2/xml2_0.4-3.1+b1_amd64.deb
Size: 13912
```

Unfortunately, that Homepage field is a 404 dead link.

I'd like to find the new home, if any, for it so that I can give out working links and also submit a bug report to debian to get the Homepage link corrected.  It seems that my google-fu is not powerful enough for this task.

Aside from the source archives in debian and other distros, does anyone know where `xml2` "lives" now?  Is there a homepage? A github repo?  Is it abandonware?

---

#### Update 2020-08-30:

The github clone/xml2 repo mentioned in the answer also seems to be abandoned now.   There's a fork of that which was last updated in Jan 2019 and has the original html documentation converted to markdown:

https://github.com/cryptorick/xml2

Comment: The site seems to have gone missing somewhere between June and November 2016 - along with the download-archive referred to.  Fortunately, both can be found on archive.org:  https://web.archive.org/web/20160730094113/http://ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/  (from July 30, 2016) and https://web.archive.org/web/20160427221603/http://download.ofb.net/gale/ (from April 27, 2016), with XML2-0.5 https://web.archive.org/web/20160427221603/http://download.ofb.net/gale/xml2-0.5.tar.gz (from May 29, 2011)

Comment: thanks. i might try emailing the author.   He still seems to be active on other projects and has a github account at https://github.com/egnor (has same ofb.net email address)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A github repo?

Well there is https://github.com/clone/xml2 .

The Debian source code incorporates all of that directly, and is hyperlinked at https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/xml2 .