# How to export *all* VMs from KVM host

Tags: bash, kvm, libvirt, virsh

Searching for a good way to export all VMs from KVM nodes so I have some backups while doing in place OS upgrade of the KVM hosts.

So far, I am using a hacky bash oneliner in order to dump all VMs as xml and list their disk paths for copying purposes:

```
for vm in $(virsh list --all | egrep -v "ID|---" | awk '{print $2}'); do virsh dumpxml "$vm" > "/root/vm/$vm.xml"; virsh domblklist "$vm" | grep '/' | awk '{print $2}' >> /root/vm/vm_disks.lst; done
```

This works well, but virsh only does "human" output AFAIK so I have to grep/awk my way around the output which is not very reliable IMO.

Is there any clean way to achieve this without the need of a python script with libvirt ?

Best regards.

Comment: Just a couple of possible improvements (I'd be fine if someone liked to make a proper answer out of this): `virsh list` (at least, version 7.10) accepts a `--name` option to only output domain names; instead of post-processing `virsh`'s output with text oriented tools, I'd just use `dumpxml` and process it's output with an XML parsing tool - e.g. use something like `xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/domain/devices/disk' -m 'source/@file' -v '.' -n` to list the paths of a domain's disk devices (possibly not safe against newline characters in file paths).

Comment: or with `-m 'source/@file|source/@dev'` or - some VMs have block devices (like partitions or LVs or ZFS zvols) for their disk devices.  And there are probably other possibilities, so `-m 'source/@*'`.    To expand on fra-san's comment:   try something based on: `for vm in $(virsh list --all --name) ; do echo "$vm:"; virsh dumpxml "$vm" | xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/domain/devices/disk' -m 'source/@*' -v '.' -n ; echo ; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example based on comments by myself and @fra-san:

(I use a mixture of ZFS zvols, qcow2 and raw files for my VMs)

```
# for vm in $(virsh list --all --name) ; do
  echo "$vm:"
  virsh dumpxml "$vm" | xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/domain/devices/disk' -m 'source/@*' -v '.' -n
  echo
done
debian10:
/dev/zvol/exp/debian10

debian9:
/dev/zvol/exp/volumes/debian9

freebsd:
/var/lib/libvirt/images/FreeBSD-10.2-RELEASE-amd64.qcow2

stretch:
/dev/zvol/exp/stretch
/var/lib/libvirt/ISO-Images/debian-9-stretch/debian-9.13.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso

ztest:
/dev/zvol/exp/volumes/ztest
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk01
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk02
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk03
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk04
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk05
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk06
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk07
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk08
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk09
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk10
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk11
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk12
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk13
/var/lib/libvirt/ztest/disk14
```

Note the ISO image for the "stretch" VM.  You may want to exclude things like that from your backups.  Or detach all CD-ROM/DVD images from VMs before extracting the list of attached virtual disks.

The `ztest` VM has a lot of virtual disks (mostly ~200MB, some 1GB each) because it's the VM I use for testing ZFS upgrades (incl. kernel compatibility with dkms module packages) and to experiment with ZFS commands before I use them on real systems.  I also use it for testing btrfs, LVM, mdadm, and other disk-related stuff.

---

Another alternative is to use `xml2` instead of `xmlstarlet`.  It's a lot simpler than xmlstarlet, and more suited to "hacky" solutions with grep and awk and sed.  It parses XML and converts it to a line-oriented format suitable for use with line-oriented tools.

```
for vm in $(virsh list --all --name) ; do
  echo "$vm:"
  virsh dumpxml "$vm" |
    xml2 |
    awk -F= '/^\/domain\/devices\/disk\/source\/@(file|dev)/ {print $2}'
  echo
done
```

Unfortunately, `xml2` seems to be abandonware these days.  You can still find it in some distros (e.g. `apt-get install xml2` on Debian) but the upstream seems to have vanished.  It's old and unmaintained and doesn't support utf8 (and could probably be replaced with 5 or 10 lines of perl or python code).  However, it's still useful for some tasks.  If you need to compile it from source yourself, see my question [where, oh where, has xml2 gone?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383507/where-oh-where-has-xml2-gone)

---

BTW, you said *"... so I have some backups while doing in place OS upgrade of the KVM hosts"* - that's one of the things that snapshots are good for.    You can do snapshots with ZVOLs, qcow2 files, and LVM.  btrfs also supports snapshots but not for individual files (and if you're using btrfs for VM images, you're probably using raw or qcow2 files for the virtual disks)

Comment: Thanks, I actually run on ZoL (moved from 0.8 series to 2.0.7 while doing this upgrade ;) so I did indeed snapshot before upgrades. I also do app aware snapshots using `virsh snapshot-create-as vm --atomic --quiesce --disk-only` but that's another story. Still, I do like to have dumped XML files, and it was more of a 'is there a non messy way of doing' question than an absolute necessity ;) Is there any advantage on using an xml parser instead over `virsh domblklist` ?

Comment: advantages? less post-processing, more certainty about what you're extracting.  Using an XML parser gives you exactly what you ask for (e.g. the path to the virtual disk), no more & no less - the exact values you want without extra quotes, whitespace, formatting, etc.  i.e. it returns data, not formatted text that you have to turn into usable data.  `virsh domblklist` gives you a text table with header lines and more details to throw away.   Sometimes those details are useful, but you can extract them from XML too. Both methods are good, depends on your needs at the time.

Comment: in short, it's: "gimme exactly what i want" vs "gimme what i want embedded somewhere in a whole bunch of stuff i don't want".