# How to diff styles between two odt files?

Tags: libreoffice

How one could diff styles embedded in two different Open Document Text file (odt) ?

For example, a person A create a file and modify the header/titles styles, store the document in a shared drive. Person B makes modification to styling and saves as, but the modification are subtle. Which tool will allow me to know which style has been modified ?

Solutions requiring to "unpack" the odt file are valid.

Just diff'ing styles.xml does not work because everything is on one line, it consider everything was changed if they are not strictly identical.

Comment: so if you can influence the workflow, tell them to enable "track changes", which solves your problem within libreoffice (you can then display who changed what).

Comment: To diff XML files, you're right, `diff` is the wrong tool (but modern `diff` variants, including the probably available `git diff` component which also works out of git repos can do better than line-wise comparison); but try https://superuser.com/questions/79920/how-can-i-diff-two-xml-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got [unzip](http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html) and [xml2](https://github.com/cryptorick/xml2) installed, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="$1"
b="$2"

diff -u <(unzip -p "$a" styles.xml | xml2) \
        <(unzip -p "$b" styles.xml | xml2)
```

`xml2` converts an XML file into plain-text suitable for processing with line-oriented tools like `grep`, `sed`, `cut`, and, of course, `diff`.  AFAICT, it's abandonware (see [where, oh where, has xml2 gone?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383507/where-oh-where-has-xml2-gone)) but it's still very useful abandonware, and still packaged by some distros (e.g. `sudo apt-get install xml2` on Debian and derivatives).

Note: .odt has changed a lot over the years, so it's possible that some versions of .odt files may keep the styles in a different file (or a sub-directory) in the zip file.   If you run across one of those, you'll have to modify the script to first examine each .odt file (e.g. with `unzip -vl`) to find out what kind of style file it has and where it is.

Personally, I wouldn't do anything too much more complicated than the script above in bash or any other shell.  I'd be inclined to use perl's [ODF::lpOD](https://metacpan.org/release/ODF-lpOD) or DIY with [Archive::Zip](https://metacpan.org/release/Archive-Zip) and one of perl's XML processing modules (maybe [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-Simple)).  Maybe [Algorithm::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Diff) too.

---

BTW, in case you didn't know `.odt` files are just a zip file containing XML, images, and other files, either in the top-level directory of the zip or in sub-directories.

Comment: Solid answer, thanks